# how to execute an local script in remote server with parameters

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I have written an bash script foo.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "starting the script";
```

I want to execute it in my remote server.
I tried `ssh user@remote-addr < test.sh` and it worked.

After that I changed the test.sh file like this

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "starting the script";
echo $1;
```

now I want to pass a local parameter to execute with my script but when I type `ssh user@remote-addr < test.sh testparam` it returns an error.

How can I pass parameters with my scripts?

Comment: See answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87405/how-can-i-execute-local-script-on-remote-machine-and-include-arguments

Comment: @Tim, ...I'm actually not sure any of the answers there are fully robust in the general case. Hmm. Might just copy my answer over there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `-s` option, which forces `bash` (or any POSIX-compatible shell) to read its command from standard input, rather than from a file named by the first positional argument. All arguments are treated as parameters to the script instead.

```
ssh user@remote-addr 'bash -s arg' < test.sh
```

Comment: Make sure you put `--` before `arg` so it is interpreted as an argument to `test.sh` instead of `bash`. Also, you probably want to use `/usr/bin/env bash`, as in the original script.

Comment: As-given, definitely correct for hardcoded arguments. Needs a bit more care to be safe for arbitrary arguments.

Comment: @Tim, the copy of `/bin/sh` evaluating the command is searching for bash in the PATH even without `env`, no?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I stand corrected. `env` is not needed in this case.

Answer (score 7):

#### With `bash` or `ksh` as `/bin/sh`

If your remote `/bin/sh` is provided by bash or ksh, you can safely do the following with an untrusted argument list, such that even malicious names (like `$(rm -rf $HOME).txt`) can be passed as arguments safely:

```
runRemote() {
  local args script

  script=$1; shift

  # generate eval-safe quoted version of current argument list
  printf -v args '%q ' "$@"

  # pass that through on the command line to bash -s
  # note that $args is parsed remotely by /bin/sh, not by bash!
  ssh user@remote-addr "bash -s -- $args" < "$script"
}
```

...thereafter:

```
runRemote test.sh testparam
```

---

#### With Any POSIX-Compliant `/bin/sh`

**Note that the following still needs to be run in `bash`, but will work correctly when the system being `ssh`'d into has a `/bin/sh` that is POSIX-baseline, so long as the remote machine has bash installed**.

To be safe against sufficiently malicious argument data (attempting to take advantage of the non-POSIX compliant quoting used by `printf %q` in bash when nonprintable characters are present in the string being escaped) even with a `/bin/sh` that is baseline-POSIX (such as `dash` or `ash`), it gets a bit more interesting:

```
runRemote() {
  local script=$1; shift
  local args
  printf -v args '%q ' "$@"
  ssh user@remote-addr "bash -s" <<EOF

  # pass quoted arguments through for parsing by remote bash
  set -- $args

  # substitute literal script text into heredoc
  $(< "$script")

EOF
}
```

Similarly invoked as:

```
runRemote test.sh testparam
```