# Shell script (on Mac OS) to SSH into a Linux/Unix server and run a command

Tags: macos, terminal, sh

I want to write a shell script to run on a Mac OS system that will do something along the lines of the following:

- SSH into a Linux server (using key authentication)
- Perform a command on the server via SSH

I would assume it'd be something like this:

```
ssh user@ip --[some kind of key auth flag here]
command --whatever-flags-here
```

Unfortunately, I don't have a Mac nor do I have any experience using them at all so I'm hoping you guys can help me out with this one.

Comment: Your question is not related to **programming**. https://superuser.com/ is a better place to ask.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to execute an local script in remote server with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40853547/how-to-execute-an-local-script-in-remote-server-with-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
ssh user@ip [ssh-options] "command1; command2; command3; ..."
```

For example:

```
ssh user@ip "touch test.txt; cp test.txt test2.txt"
```

will create the two empty files test.txt and test2.txt on the remote machine.

Another approach would be to use a stdin redirection

```
ssh user@ip [ssh-options] < your_commands.sh
```

where `your_commands.sh` is the script that will executed on the remote machine.